# setting up node.js and codiad with nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, vim, nginx

I was wondering if someone out there could help me with all of this?,

I started of creating my ubuntuserver 14.04 with this link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

then to turn it into a production server I then did this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

(the above works well to serve my node.js app)

But what I am wondering is how can I install and configure nginx to work with installing codiad so that i can access the node.js apps that i create on the same server, instead of using vim or nano...

Another question is that if i cannot install codiad, is there a way that i can use chrome dev editor to git push (i know that this can be done), to the node.js apps, I did follow alot of articles explaining how to do this, and i was able to set things up but it was like giving permission errors, could not make head or tales of it even if i did change permissions...

So i was wondering if anyone has configured Node.js and nginx and git push and clone to work all together, and maybe to install codiad on the same server to make coding easier?

Hope some can help me..:)

Comment: Why don't you **try** all those things instead of asking random strangers if it's possible?

Comment: I have already tried and asked only if anyone had been able to accomplish this... no need to b rude sir

Comment: Laziness begets rudeness.

Comment: Im sorry you think that way.. but I have gotten certain steps to work on my own.. and with research.. I was only asking if anyone had been able to do something like what I am asking.. there is no harm in asking if you can only go so far when doing things yourself... even after asking the question I am still researching on how I can do this.. so no.. I am not being lazy

Answer (score 0):

From the "Requirements" part of Codiad's homepage:

> Codiad requires a minimal server installation with Apache2, PHP 5+ and basic r/w access to several directories. There is no database requirement

Since none of the linked tutorials mentions either Apache or PHP we are forced to assume that your server doesn't meet those requirements and that you simply can't install that pseudo IDE. If you really want that thing on your server [the next step](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/wiki/Installation) is rather obvious.

For further questions regarding Codiad I suggest using [their issue tracker](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/issues) instead of any Stack Exchange site. You'll have a lot more chances of getting a useful answers there.

Installing a gimmicky pseudo-IDE on your server is *useless*. Instead:

- develop locally (ideally in a virtual machine that looks like your application server), using whatever IDE/text editor you are most comfortable with,
- use your favorite version control system to push your master branch on your actual server when ready.